# Reading the keyboard in python without getting into a blocking call?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a python code that tracks the mouse and the keyboard. I want the tracking of both to be in a single while loop like the following:

```
while True:
    mouse_x, mouse_y = get_mouse_pos()
    key_pressed = get_key_pressed()
    print(key_pressed + " is down")
    print(f"The mouse position is: {mouse_x}, {mouse_y}")
```

Is there any way to do so without opening a thread for the keyboard reading?

I couldn't find a method that reads the keyboard without waiting for an input. I tried `kbhit()` in `msvcrt` module, but it only returns 0 no matter what I press, and the `keyboard` module can read only a specific key non blockingly as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I can use pygame.event.get() to iterate through the events, catch a key down or a key up event, and get the unicode of the key that was down/up.

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print(str(event.unicode) + " is down")

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            print(str(event.unicode) + " is up")
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you will need to use **two threads** to monitor both the keyboard and the mouse at the same time, **without blocking**. You can create event listeners to monitor for both.

Note that I have incorporated an **exit key** `x` which will exit the program when pressed.

Here is an example of how that could be achieved:

#### Code:

```
from pynput import mouse, keyboard
import sys
import threading

exit_program = False

def on_press(key):
    global exit_program
    try:
        print(f'Key {key.char} was pressed.')
        if key.char == "x":
            exit_program = True
            sys.exit()
    except AttributeError:
        print(f'Special key {key} was pressed.')

def on_move(x, y):
    global exit_program
    if exit_program:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print(f'Mouse moved to (x:{x} , y:{y})')


# Collect events from both keyboard and mouse
def start_listener_keyboard():
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()

def start_listener_mouse():
    with mouse.Listener(on_move=on_move) as listener:
        listener.join()

threading.Thread(target=start_listener_keyboard).start()
threading.Thread(target=start_listener_mouse).start()
```

#### Output:

```
Mouse moved to (x:1543 , y:210)
Mouse moved to (x:1543 , y:208)
Mouse moved to (x:1544 , y:206)
Mouse moved to (x:1544 , y:205)
Mouse moved to (x:1544 , y:201)
Mouse moved to (x:1544 , y:197)
Mouse moved to (x:1544 , y:195)
Mouse moved to (x:1544 , y:193)
Key d was pressed.
Mouse moved to (x:1544 , y:192)
Mouse moved to (x:1544 , y:188)
Mouse moved to (x:1543 , y:187)
Special key Key.backspace was pressed.
Key x was pressed.
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I already found a way to track the mouse without getting into a blocking call using `pyautogui.position()`. It would be weird if there wasn't a way to do something similar with the keyboard